# Estimating an unusual infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I came across the following summation, which I would like to estimate. I only need an answer which is correct up to a constant multiple; one can assume that $a, b, c$ are real numbers in the range $[0,1]$ which are small. (The estimate can assume that $a,b,c$ are arbitrarily small):
$$
S = \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{(1+a)^k}{(b^{\frac{1}{k-1}} + c)^k}
$$

Note that as long as $a \leq c$ this sum converges, for the denominator approaches to $(1+c)^k$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Really, I only need a bound of the form
$$
S = O(f(a,b,c))
$$
for $a,b,c$ sufficiently small.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $N$
  sufficiently large and assuming $a<c$
 . We have $$\sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(\frac{1+a}{b^{1/(1-k)}+c}\right)^{k}\leq\sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(\frac{1+a}{b^{1/(1-N)}+c}\right)^{k}.$$
 Let $$r:=\frac{1+a}{b^{1/(1-N)}+c};$$
 if $N$
  is large we have $r<1$
  so $$\sum_{k=2}^{N}r^{k}=\frac{r^{2}-r^{N+1}}{1-r}.$$
 Now note that $$r^{N+1}\rightarrow0$$
 and $$\frac{1+a}{b^{1/(1-N)}+c}\rightarrow\frac{1+a}{1+c}$$
 as $N\rightarrow\infty.$
  So $$\sum_{k\geq2}\left(\frac{1+a}{b^{1/(1-k)}+c}\right)^{k}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(\frac{1+a}{b^{1/(1-k)}+c}\right)^{k}\leq\left(\frac{1+a}{1+c}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1+c}{c-a}\right)=\frac{1+a}{\left(1+c\right)\left(c-a\right)}.$$